# Does changing a Service from Automatic to Manual mean that it is unable to be started by other services/applications?

Tags: windows, active-directory, sql

Morning all. We have a script that checks for services that are set to Automatic, but not running. It alerts us if this is the case. We've got a couple of services, like SQL Server Active Directory Helper, which are set to Automatic. They start, but are not required, so they don't stay running. (It appears that are started on-demand by SQL.)

Can we change them to Manual without affecting their ability to be started by applications on-demand.

Cheers.

Comment: If the services were configured as Automatic by default there is probably a reason.  If you configured them as Automatic it should be safe to change them back.  Basically you need to look at the documentation for each of the services in question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you modify the script to allow these services as an exemption.

Microsoft introduced this concept of Automatic services that only run when needed only a few years back, but it is now common practice.

There are many other services with similar behavior, i.e some .Net services, Software Protection.

Going ahead and modifying the system to suit you script is not a recommended approach.